# List variables with type and where they are defined in a Fortran 77 program

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Is there any way to list all the variables that are defined in a Fortran 77 program, including

1. where the variable is defined?
2. which type the variable has?

I was hoping there might either be some dedicated software that could do this, or some compiler flags with e.g. gfortran.

Comment: Note that questions for external tool recommendation are off-topic. That said, there are various tools and some IDE will probably be able to do that. Have you tried Visual Studio (even the old Powerstation one)? Or Eclipse/Photran?

Comment: Although off-topic. Are we you talking about local variables or global (/ module, i.e. not fortran77) variables? Maybe look at doxygen *REFERENCE.... in the Doxyfile. Please move /ask issue to / at "Software recommendations".

Comment: Thanks for the input. How would I move the question to a more relevant site, e.g. the "Software recommendations" site? I would guess only moderators could do that.

Comment: Just delete this one and open a new one. Be sure to reformulate it following their requirements. The current  title, for example, does not look like a software search.

Comment: Picking up all _potential variables_ is easy using the following regex `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`. The problem occurs when you have to distinguish keywords. Imagine a line like `if if then then=1.0; end if` where `if` and `then` are implicitly defined ...

Comment: Just for potential use, we can print the symbol tree in each routine by "gfortran -fdump-fortran-original (or -fdump-parse-tree) test.f", which might give another way to get some info...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `grep`? This is a short snippet to give you the occurrences of the base types:

```
for i in byte character integer logical \
         real "double[[:blank:]]+precision" \
         complex "double[[:blank:]]+complex" ; do 
    grep -Ein "^[[:blank:]]*${i}[[:blank:]\*(,:]" $(find . -name "*.[fF]*")
done
```

Of course, this will only work if you are using explicit type declaration throughout your code.

Explanation:

Use `grep` with regular expressions (`-E`) and case-insensitive matches (`-i`) to print out the line number and file (`-n`) on all Fortran files `*.[fF]*` in the current folder.

The Regex is:

```
"^[[:blank:]]*                       Only whitespaces (if any) in the beginning
              ${i}                   Followed by the variable type
                  [[:blank:]\*(,:]"  Followed immediately by a whitespace, "*", 
                                     "(", ",", or ":"
```

Comment: This answer is probably a good demonstration that what is wanted is decidedly non-trivial.  I wouldn't use this approach unless I was already fairly confident of what I was going to get out.